# Webstorm: cannot resolve angularjs anchor (hashtag) references to other files

Tags: angularjs, webstorm, ngroute

I've got a working Angular app. Navigation is implemented using ngRoute. All works well. But, when trying to leverage Webstorm navigation feature from my HTML file by clicking on href="#XXX" tag, I get a reference error (from Webstorm).

"XXX" is defined in my angular.module like this -

```
   .config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/XXX', {
    templateUrl: 'XXX/my-file.html',
    controller: 'MyCtrl'
  });
```

and the reference inside the HTML (which works in run time) is like this -

```
<a href="#XXX">my link text</a>
```

From the message itself, it looks like Webstorm is looking for the anchor inside the same HTML file and is not actually considering the ngRoute definition.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just got a reply from Webstorm official support - currently this behavior is not supported. I thus created a respective request on their tracker - https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-17238. You're welcome to vote for it:-).

Answer (score 0):

Try including:

```
$locationProvider
```

in your routes file and then putting:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

below your route declarations. Then in your html file include:

```
<base href='/'>
```

in your head. This will allow you to use routing without the '#' symbol. Not sure if that answers your question or not but it should get you on the right path.

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't seem to get Webstorm to do the job. It's still not using the routing configuration. So it now understands it should navigate to some other file (vs. an anchor inside this file) but it is looking for a file named "XXX" instead of looking for "XXX/my-file.html" as specified in the routing configuration.

Comment: It may be something to do with your server side code then. You need to set a static reference to the root folder of your angular app. I use node a lot, which does that like this:

`var express                         = require('express'),
app                                     = express(),
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/app'));`

Comment: I will try to clarify. My app **is** working fine. In fact, I have that piece of code you've suggested I should add to my server side already (I'm also using node and express). The problem is how Webstorm interprets the code for navigating between files in the editor. It seems like it doesn't understand the XXX in `href=XXX` refers to a route path (for which a _templateUrl_ is configured) but takes it as the HTML template file name itself.

Comment: Is the code you posted in your example the complete routes code?

Comment: Nope. Here it is (more or less) `angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngResource']).config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/status', {
    templateUrl: 'status/my-status.html',
    controller: 'StatusCtrl'
  });
  $routeProvider.when('/status/my-status', {
    templateUrl: 'status/my-status.html',
    controller: 'StatusCtrl'
  });
  $routeProvider.when('/status/others-status', {
    templateUrl: 'status/others-status.html',
    controller: 'StatusCtrl'
  });
}])`

Comment: Hmmm. Does your first route work? I know that normally you would chain your routes together like this:


`angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngResource']).config(['$routeProvider', 
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/status', {
     templateUrl: 'status/my-status.html',
     controller: 'StatusCtrl'
    })
    .when('/status/my-status', {
     templateUrl: 'status/my-status.html',
     controller: 'StatusCtrl'
    })
    .when('/status/others-status', {
     templateUrl: 'status/others-status.html',
     controller: 'StatusCtrl'
    });
  }
]);
`

Comment: It **does** work for me as is. But, just in case, I've changed it to your way. Still Webstorm wouldn't use it. It looks like there should be a way to tell it the "href=" is not referring to a file name but, rather, to an ngRoute path but I can't figure out if/how this can be done.

Comment: I am not too sure then man, maybe there is a plugin or something that you need to be able to use Angular with Webstorm. Seems as though there are a decent amount of issues with trying to use Angular in that IDE.

Comment: I would have expected the same but looks like this feature is missing. See  https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-17238.

Comment: Wow yeah. Well hopefully they resolve that issue quickly.

Answer (score 0):

If you use ui-router rather than ngRoute you do not have to use the you can use the attribute ui-sref

e.g; `<a ui-sref="XXX">my link text</a>`